# Is AB = A x B in Image Manipulation?

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, image-resizing

I am making a blog-like platform, and now I am working on the part to save pictures. I want to store pictures under the file size limit and want my users to rotate pictures to proper orientation before sending them to the server. In an easy way, I can do this way:

1.Read a file and resize if it is bigger than the limit.

```
//Make a blob
var blob = new Blob([oFREvent.target.result]);
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

//Make Image object to resize on client side
var picture = new Image();
picture.src = blobURL;

//Resize. Create resized Image Object
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(picture, 0, 0, picturewidth, pictureheight, 0, 0, maxwidth, proportionalheight);
var resizedPicture = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
```

2.Show the preview of the picture to a user, and the user rotates the picture if
    necessary.

3.Rotate the Image

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

//rotate by 90 degrees. maxwidth in step 2 = maxheight in step 3
ctx.rotate(90 * Math.PI/180); 
ctx.drawImage(resizedPicture, 0, 0, picturewidth, pictureheight, proportionalheight, maxheight);
var resizedRotatedPicture = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
```

This approaches require drawing a picture twice in jpg format. Is not this lossy? Should I resize and rotate again with original blob in step 3 or should I output dataURL in png in step 1 and change it to jpg in step 3?

Comment: Scaling -> to jpeg -> rotate -> to jpeg will add additional compression noise. Just don't do the compression step in the middle. The canvas can be drawn just like an image so for the second step use the canvas as the image source. The canvas is double buffered as well so you can render the canvas on top of itself. eg first step `ctx.drawImage(picture, ...` then `ctx.rotate(angle); ctx.drawImage(ctx.canvas, ...`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response! I will try :)